# Ownership of custom list

Tags: user-profile-property

I have created a custom list(database) which is on a specific site. I would like to let people know who the creator of that list is. I need to add something like a digital signature or "copyright" for the custom list that I made. The purpose is to let people know who made the list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried list description section? It is similar with SP2010 and SP2013.

Under List Settings --> Title, description and navigation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In SharePoint 2013 is the description hidden under the Info icon which the user have to click to show it.

Comment: thank you for your solutions, But is there any other solution without actually the need to click somewhere?

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript? Maybe you can do this using jQuery or JSLink.